# Best way to use JQuery in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I would like to manipulate html code with jquery on the serverside. The server is running on node.js. The html code is stored as string in the variable 'myHtmlVariable'. For the project I found node-jsdom.

I need to change several ids in the stored html code. It doesn´t work so far. I tried following:

```
    let jsdom = require("jsdom");
    let dom = new jsdom.JSDOM('');
    let $ = require("jquery")(dom.window);
  

    // Creating the required window
    dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(myHtmlVariable);  // stored html as string

    for (let k = 0; k < IDs.length; k++){  
    
       $('#' + IDs[k].find).attr("id", 'IDs[k].set'); 
    
      
   }

   console.log(dom.serialize());
```

- Is my approach right?
- How do I get the manipulated html code?
- Is there a better way to solve the task?

Would be happy for some help. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does it _"not work"_? Did you perhaps mean to use `.attr("id", IDs[k].set)` (no quotes around the value)?

Comment: I am not able to check whether it is working, because I can't retrieve the manipulated text file.

Comment: What is your end goal?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: FYI, you can call `dom.serialize()` to generate HTML from your modified DOM.

Comment: ... but do it _after_ your `for` loop. I would also make sure you're attaching jQuery to the parsed HTML document, not the initial empty one

Comment: The end goal is to manipulate a string with html in node js with jquery. I have to change ids and attributes in the stored html string. As I have all ids and values of the attributes stored, it would be the easiest way to loop through all data and prepare the html code...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was, that I have to define `let $ = require("jquery")(dom.window);` each time I change the dom. What makes totally sense...

```
    let jsdom = require("jsdom");
      
    // Creating the required window
    dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(myHtmlVariable);  // stored html as string
    let $ = require("jquery")(dom.window);
    
    for (let k = 0; k < IDs.length; k++){  
       $('#' + IDs[k].find).attr("id", 'IDs[k].set'); 
    }

   console.log(dom.serialize());
```